# Accessing Pandas DataFrame with Index Removed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a pandas data frame by reading data from MySql. There will always be one row in the data frame at a time. From this data frame, I'm trying to access few columns.

```
 try:
        if str(df_from_sql_query_1['age']) != "":
            age_temp = str(df_from_sql_query_1['age'])
            age = age_temp.strip()
        else:      
            print("Age is missing")
....
....
```

But when I do a print, the index value gets appended to the actual age value.

```
print("Age is", age)
```

Output:

```
Age is 0    32.0
```

Whereas I expect the output to be:

```
Age is 32.0
```

What changes shall I do to get desired output?

Comment: "There will always be one row in the data frame at a time."  Just a polite suggestion, this sounds a bit sub-optimal

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Brad. I have a synchronous job, which will give some computed value for every call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are doing `df_from_sql_query_1['age']` pandas still accesses it as a column and not as the value. you need to specify the row. If you have one row, access row 0 with

```
age_temp = df_from_sql_query_1.loc[0,'age']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform any dataframe to a String without an index by transforming it as such

```
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

You can check the other parameters in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html).

Alternatively, as your dataframe always only contains one row, you might give this a shot (I don't know about your df_from_sql_query_1() function)

```
 age = str(df_from_sql_query_1[0]['age']).strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this replacement should work:

```
age_temp = str(df_from_sql_query_1['age'].values[0])
age = age_temp.strip()
```